# optimization of CountourPlot with NIntegrate

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization

I have to use `ContourPlot` with a complicated function depending on 2 parametrs (that I cannot report here) that contains numerical integrations.

Here is a simple example to clarify my problem:

```
f[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ] := NIntegrate[a*x + b, {x, 0, 1}];
ContourPlot[{f[a, b] == 3, f[a, b] == 6, f[a, b] == 10}, {a, 0, 
   10}, {b, 0, 10}] // Timing
```

[image]

As you can see, since Nintegrate is evaluated in every point, the computation is very slow (over 3 seconds on my laptop, even for this simple case): how can I optimize this?

Comment: `ContourPlot[f[a, b], {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 10}, Contours -> {3, 6, 10}] // Timing` isn't probably the best solution, but it shaves the time by 40%

Comment: Maybe also play with the number of `PlotPoints`.

Comment: this is redundantly computing the Integral at some points, saving values ( `f[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ] := f[a,b]= NIntegrate..` ) cuts the time in half for this example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** Using the memoization  trick suggested by @george2079 in the comments combined with  `MeshFunctions` we get the same picture in `0.015625 seconds`:

```
fa[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := fa[a, b] = NIntegrate[a*x + b, {x, 0, 1}];
First@Timing[ContourPlot[fa[a, b], {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 10}, Contours -> {}, 
    ContourShading -> None, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
    Mesh -> {{{3, Red}, {6, Green}, {10, Blue}}}, 
    MeshStyle -> Thick] /. Polygon[__] -> Sequence[]]
(* 0.015625 *)
```

---

**Original post:**

Using `MeshFunctions` with no contours

```
First@Timing[cp1 = ContourPlot[f[a, b], {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 10}, 
   Contours -> {}, ContourShading -> None,
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{{3, Red}, {6, Green}, {10, Blue}}}, 
   MeshStyle -> Thick]/. Polygon[__] -> Sequence[]]
(* 0.578125 *)
```

makes it faster

```
cp1
```

[image]

versus

```
First@Timing[ContourPlot[f[a, b], {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 10}, Contours -> {3, 6, 10}]]
(* 1.625000 *)
```

Comment: I cannot avoid numerical integrations

Comment: @belisarius, mattiav27, sorry i missed the key requirement of the question:)

Comment: Much better now. +1 `cp1 /. GrayLevel[_] :> GrayLevel[1]`

Comment: It is important to see why this is fast: here the function value is computed on a regular grid and the contours are based on simple interpolation. In the approach in the question `ContourPlot` uses a root finding algorithm to accurately find the locus of the contours.

Comment: @george, good point, thank you. Actually, `MeshFunctions` combined with your memoization suggestion cuts the timing to almost zero.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative for how to speed up the plotting if you want to retain all the functionality and options of `ContourPlot`: use `ParallelTable`:

```
f[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[a*x + b, {x, 0, 1}];

Timing[Show[
  ParallelTable[
   ContourPlot[f[a, b], {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 10}, Contours -> {i}, 
    ContourShading -> None, 
    ContourStyle -> Hue[i/10]], {i, {3, 6, 10}}]]]
```

This is a little slower than kguler's solution, but I think it will depend on the actual function to be plotted, and on the complexity of the contour lines you want to see. My solution simply offloads the computation of each individual contour onto a separate kernel, by making a `ParallelTable` of `ContourPlot`s for one contour each. Then I combine them with `Show` at the end.

You could in principle combine kguler's and my suggestion to speed things up still  more, but I just want to point out the parallelization aspect in making the plot.