# How to speed up plotting of Sophomore's Dream function

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, performance-tuning, special-functions

Let $$\textbf{Sphd}(\alpha;x)=\int_{0}^xt^{\alpha t}dt$$

I want make a graphic like this by using *Mathematica*

[image]

I tried:

```
Plot[Table[NIntegrate[t^(a t), {t, 0, x}], {a, -1, 10, 1}], {x, 1, 4}]
```

but it is very slow..

Comment: It is slow because it evaluates every time the `NIntegrate`. You should try with memoization: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html

Comment: This question of mine can be useful in your case too: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73714/8822

Comment: you should use `NDSolve` instead of `NIntegrate` . Do a search here there are numerous examples. Here is one http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101784/2079, there are probably better ones.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to the [Sophomore's Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream) function! Neat!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Reformulation as a `ParametricNDSolve[]` problem is very fast:

```
ff = 10;
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[t] == (t + $MachineEpsilon)^(a t), 
   y[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, ff}, {a}]

LogPlot[Evaluate[
  Table[pfun[a][
    x], {a, {-50, -30, -20, -10, -5, -1, 0, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 
     10}}]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {1, 10^10}]
```

[image: sophomore's dream]

Comment: I think `y[0]` should be `0`.

Comment: @george2079 I assume anything in power of 0 is 1, i.e. a^0 =1. Limit of t^t as t->0  is 1.

Comment: absolutely, that makes `y'[0]==1` so the integral is zero in the limit. compare your plot at zero to the original.

Comment: @george2079. Ok, indeed, the initial condition should be replaced in order to match the original problem

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps slightly faster:

```
f[a_, x_] := NIntegrate[t^(a t), {t, 0, x}]
al = {-50, -30, -20, -10, -5, -1, 0, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10};
tab[a_] := Table[{j, f[a, j]}, {j, 0, 10, 0.1}]
ListLogPlot[tab /@ al, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {0.01, 10^10}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Automatic, al], 
 GridLines -> {Range[10], PowerRange[1, 10^10, 10]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]