# Memoization and finding already calculated DownValue

Tags: recursion, core-language, searching, memoization, downvalues

The problem of plotting an expensive function discussed in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137083/34848) caught my attention. As an exercies I tried to solve it using [memoization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)  as follows

```
ClearAll[fn]
fn[0, a_] = 1;
fn[xEnd_, a_] := 
fn[xEnd, a] = 
Module[{xPrev},(* Find the last known xPrev such that xPrev<xEnd *) ; 
    fn[xPrev, a] + NIntegrate[t^(a t), {t, xPrev, xEnd}]]
```

In the comment `(* Find the last known xPrev such that xPrev<xEnd *)`, I need to add code to find a point `xPrev` such that `xPrev<xEnd` and `fn[xPrev,a]` is is already calculated. Basically, search within existing downvalues to see the highest `xPrev` satisfying the given condition that is already solved. Afterwards, I just calculate the portion of the integral from `xPrev` until the `xEnd`.

**My question is: What is the best way to find this particular `DownValue` from within the fn? Is this in general a good practice?**

Please do not focus specifically on the quoted problem. I just used it as a reference to describe the problem.

Comment: you can grab the previously existing values via something like `Cases[
 DownValues@fn,
 fn[x_?NumericQ,_] :> x, Infinity]`

Comment: Tried already,but I'm having problems making heads and tails of those `Hold`, `HoldPattern` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a silly example to show how you can use `Cases` to grab the previously input values of a function and apply some test to them.  Here the function is simply going to return a list of the largest previously input `x` that's smaller than the current `x`, and the sum of the two input values

```
ClearAll[fn]
fn[x_,a_]:= fn[x,a]= Module[{xprev},
    xprev =Max @ Cases[
            DownValues[fn],
            HoldPattern[fn[xx_?(NumericQ[#]&&#<x&),_]]:>xx,
            Infinity];
    {xprev,x+a}
]

fn[1, a]
fn[2, a]
fn[75, a]
fn[36, a]
fn[-10, a]
fn[125, a]
(* {-∞, 1 + a} *)
(* {1, 2 + a} *)
(* {2, 75 + a} *)
(* {2, 36 + a} *)
(* {-∞, -10 + a} *)
(* {75, 125 + a} *)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping to get.

Answer (score 1):

One way to use memoization for computing integrals is to split the integral into many segments and evaluate them separately. So if you want to integrate from 1 to 10 for example, then you can integrate from 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 4 and so on. You can save each segment so that if you later want to integrate from 1 to 4 this can be done instantaneously using stored values.

This is what the implementation could look like:

```
fn[start_, a_] := fn[start, a] = NIntegrate[t^(a t), {t, start, start + 1}]

steps[start_, end_] := Range[Floor[start], Floor[end - 1]]

fn[start_, end_, a_] := Module[{first, last, intermediate},
  first = NIntegrate[t^(a t), {t, Floor[start], start}];
  last = NIntegrate[t^(a t), {t, Floor[end], end}];
  intermediate = fn[#, a] & /@ steps[start, end];
  Total[intermediate] - first + last
  ]
```

`steps` is a function which computes the segments.

```
steps[11.5, 17.4]
```

> `{11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}`

`fn[start_, end_, a_]` takes care of fractional parts separately. Let's try it:

```
fn[1.4, 3.7, 1]
```

> `57.8109`

```
NIntegrate[t^( t), {t, 1.4, 3.7}]
```

> `57.8109`

Let's look at what values I have stored. At this point, I've evaluated other integrals as well, at least up to $t = 10$ from $t = 1$.

[image]

Comment: nice trick. However, I would still like to know a way to search in `DownValues` for the last solution and than just add incrementally from that solution until the end of the region of interest. I posted this question more because of curiosity and it is not an actual problem that I'm facing now. So please do not take me wrong.

Comment: This is not, generally, how you want to memoize integrals. Store the integrals from 1 to 2, from 1 to 3, from 1 to 4... . Then you can find the integral from a to b by (integral from 1 to b) - (integral from 1 to a). Turns it from O(n) into O(1)

Comment: @AlexMeiburg I was just creating a toy example to show something that is more idiomatic than what OP is suggesting. I'm not proposing that anyone should use this.

Comment: Right right, just adding this in case someone else does plan to. :)